# How to find the greatest power of 2 dividing a number using GMP?

Tags: gmp

According to the GMP documentation [here](http://www.intel.com/software/products/mkl/docs/gnump/WebHelp/number_theoretic_functions.htm):

> Function: unsigned long int mpz_remove
>   (mpz_t rop, mpz_t op, mpz_t f)
>
> Remove all occurrences of the factor f
>   from op and store the result in rop.
>   The return value is how many such
>   occurrences were removed.

So the mpz_remove function should be able to be used to answer the titled question.  At the moment my code looks like this:

```
  mpz_set_ui(temp2,2);
  mpz_remove(temp,K0,temp2);
```

which works fine, but the result I want is K0 divided by temp (and not temp itself) [which I could get by adding a subsequent division operation, but that seems wasteful].

> How should I actually get K0/temp?

Answer (score 1):

You might try the combination of mpz_scan1() and mpz_tdiv_q_2exp().

```
mpz_tdiv_q_2exp(result,K0,mpz_scan1(K0,0))
```